# How to use methods from other classes?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to get a rectangle application to work , the purpose is to let the user input the length and width but I don't know how to call the methods and get the user input to be displayed in my output.

here is my class (langd = lenght , bredd = width  in swedish)

```
namespace _10._3
{
class Rectangle
{
    private double langd;
    private double bredd;

    public Rectangle()
    {

        langd = 1.0;
        bredd = 1.0;

    }
    public Rectangle(double langden, double bredden)
    {
        langd = langden;
        bredd = bredden;

    }

    public double langden

    {
        get
        {
            return langd;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value < 20)
                langden = value;

            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("längd", value, "langde måste vara mer än 0 och mindre än 20  ");
        }

    }
    public double bredden
    {
        get {
            return bredd;

        }
        set {
            if (value > 0 && value < 20)
                bredd = value;

            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bredd", value, "bredden måste vara mer än 0 och mindre än 20");

        }
    }
    public double omkrats
    {
        get
        {
            return 2 * langd + 2 * bredd;
        }
    }
    public double area{
    get {
    return langd * bredd;
    }


    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}{2}: {3}{4}: {5}{6}: {7}", "Längd", langd, "bredd", bredd, "Omkräts", omkrats, "Area", area);  



    }

}
```

}

Here is my program:

```
namespace _10._3
{
    class test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();


            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in längden :");
            rectangle.langden = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in bredden :");
            rectangle.bredden = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine(rectangle.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Längd :" );
            Console.WriteLine("Bredd :");
            Console.WriteLine("Omkräts:");
            Console.WriteLine("Area");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what language is this ?? :)

Comment: @LittleChild I'd bet my soul that's C#.

Comment: @Renan no, please don't.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to use the property getters/setters?(you seem to be using the setters just fine)

Just treat them as variables

```
Console.WriteLine("Längd : " + rectangle.langden.ToString() );
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Längd : {0}", rectangle.langden );
```

Comment: on a related note, the common naming standard would probably name your length property `Langd`

Comment: ok thanks ! just what i was looking for :) but i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in 10.3.exe

Comment: @user2456264 the reason for that is because when you do `langden = value;` you're essentially calling the setter from within itself.  change that line to `langd = value;
`